# getchar() unexpected behavior

Tags: c, getchar

```
char ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
    putchar(ch);
}
```

The above code, obviously enough, should copy my input. And it does work, for basic ASCII text files.

However, if I send it a gif, in particular this one, but applicable to most (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~peterson/prog2/smile.gif), then when I redirect stdin for the gif, and stdout to any file type, and run diff on the original and the new one, errors galore. In this case, more than half of the file isn't even processed, it simply quits.
Any clues? I'd be willing to switch off to another input/output functions, provided I can input a byte at a time.

Comment: `getchar` is reading the standard input as text, not general binary. `gif` is a binary file.

Comment: Yeah, open binary files as binary files.

Comment: getchar returns an int, not a char.

Comment: The distinction between text and binary generally doesn't matter on Unix-like systems. Are you on Windows? If possible, you should use `fopen()` to open a new file, given the name of the `.gif` input, rather than reading it from `stdin` (which is in text mode by default). You might be able to switch `stdin` to binary mode, but I'm not certain of that.

Comment: I'm on linux, debian, if that matters. Would freopen and fread convert to binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`. The distinction is important because it might return `EOF` which is a value which cannot be a char.

You can't reliably test for EOF if you convert the return value of `getchar` to a `char`. The loop will terminate when you hit the character whose value is `(char)EOF`.

Fix it by declaring `ch` as an `int`.

Comment: Is value returned by getchar(), excluding EOF, still within the range of a normal char?, so no 2 ^ 30 ... ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by it being unreliable?

Comment: Actually, I just looked it up. That behaviour is determined by the standard, so getchar() will always return either EOF or an integer in the range representable as an *unsigned* char, regardless of whether `char` is signed or unsigned. You can't count on EOF being -1; just that it's not in the range of an unsigned char.